# AJAX how to set animation for appearing element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

How to set up animation to element once it appears? (So that others with same properties remain calm.) I am trying to do like this:

```
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
            if(obj['Ping'] == "FALSE"){
                out = "<li class='red'>"+obj.Vardas+" is down..."+obj.Data+"</li>";
                /////animation, once the element gets generated
                $(out).prependTo('#database').animate({fontColor:"red", 1000});
                out ="";
            }else{
                out = "<li>"+obj.Vardas+" is up......."+obj.Data+"</li>";
                $(out).prependTo('#database');
                out ="";    
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="float:right; overflow-y:scroll; height: 400px; width: 50%">
        <ul id ='database'></ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: jQuery is not able to animate fontColor and other color properties. And I did not understand what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to make li element to blink when it gets generated.

Comment: I have edited answer under. (To make effect of blink using opacity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery is not able to use color for animation. But for such things you can use jQuery Color plugin ( https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color ).

Here is small working example with opacity blink:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var t = function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            $("<li>ata" + i + "tata</li>").prependTo($("ul")).animate({opacity: 0.10}, 200).animate({opacity: 1}, 200);
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        setInterval(t, 1000);
    });

  </script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul> </ul>
</body>
</html>
```